# maven dependency for joda-time:joda-time-jsptags:jar:1.0.2

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to install the spring petcare application in my eclipse/tomcat7 installation, and I am getting the following error message when I try `Run As..Maven Build` in eclipse:

```
POM for joda-time:joda-time-jsptags:jar:1.0.2 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Here is [a link to the complete stack trace](https://jumpshare.com/v/d1yC9zz7Grcay9rO2SBq).  And here is [a link to pom.xml](https://jumpshare.com/v/6iLqGVHgIrabv1elFAoW).  The entire code for the application [can be found at this link](https://github.com/rajgowda/spring-petcare).  I have not changed anything in the application's code yet because I have not even gotten it to compile.

The jar in question seems to be in my local maven repository, so the problem may be that the app is simply not seeing it.

Can anyone help me get this to compile?

Answer (score 1):

Actually looking at http://search.maven.org and the [pom for that artifact is indeed missing](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22joda-time%22%20AND%20a%3a%22joda-time-jsptags%22)! However the pom later version does exist.

Assuming that artifact is backward compatible I think you can fix it simply by upgrading joda-time-jsptags to 1.1.

Find and update following dependency on the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Updated my answer to include a hacky way of forcing the jar into your local repository. Btw also check your $M2_HOME/settings.xml as you could have another settings file there

Comment: Not aware m2e has any gui to install an artifact

Comment: Sorry I missed it, the pom for 1.0.2 is indeed missing. Updated my answer. I think you're getting this error maybe because newer version of Maven had a hard requirement of having the pom in place or else it will fail

Comment: First of all that isn't same error by any means. That is a unit testing error possibly caused by bad code. You can skip it by adding `-DskipTests` argument on maven run configuration

Comment: Sorry I think you should spend some time learning maven, command line and programming in general as opposed of keep trolling in here. There isn't any shortcut in programming.